# Store text input as variable instead of number in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm currently using the below code to facilitate a login form in Microsoft Access for my users. It was originally designed to accept Username ID's from the column `UserID` which was an autonumber column inside the table `Employees Table`.

The code is working correctly, however I would like to no longer use User ID's and instead use a column I created called `Username` linked to the combo box `cbo_Employee` in order to validate the correct username with the password.

I believe the value is currently being stored in `lngMyUsername` but it will only store numbers, and if I try to set it as a `string` I get a datatype mismatch on the line `If Me.txt_Password.Value <> DLookup("Password", "Employees Table", "[Username]=" & lngMyUsername) Then`

Attached is some pictures outlining the structure of my `Employees Table` and `cbo_Employees` data properties.

[image: Table Design]
[image: Table Data]

[image: Combo Box Properties]

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. If you require anymore information please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks,
Giles.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
        'Check to see if data is entered into the Username combo box
    Dim lngMyUsername As Long
    If IsNull(Me.cbo_Employee) Or Me.cbo_Employee = "" Then
        MsgBox "You Must enter a Username.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.cbo_Employee.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    lngMyUsername = Me.cbo_Employee.Value

    'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

If IsNull(Me.txt_Password) Or Me.txt_Password = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.txt_Password.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check value of password in Employees Table to see if this matches value chosen in combo box
If Me.txt_Password.Value <> DLookup("Password", "Employees Table", "[Username]=" & lngMyUsername) Then
    MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
    Me.txt_Password.SetFocus
    Me.txt_Password = Null
    intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
    'If user enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown
    If intLogonAttempts >= 3 Then
        MsgBox "You do not  have access to this database. Please contact your system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If

Else
    Me.txt_Password = Null
    'Open correct form
    Dim strAccessLevel As String

    strAccessLevel = DLookup("Admins", "Employees Table", "Username=" & lngMyUsername)

    If strAccessLevel = "Admin" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("EmployeeName", "Employees Table", "Username=" & lngMyUsername)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "A"
    ElseIf strAccessLevel = "Manager" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("EmployeeName", "Employees Table", "Username=" & lngMyUsername)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "B"
    ElseIf strAccessLevel = "User" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("EmployeeName", "Employees Table", "Username=" & lngMyUsername)
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "C"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Edit: Below is the revised code, this will be updated again when working correctly.

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
        'Check to see if data is entered into the Username combo box
    Dim strMyUsername As String
    Dim RS As Recordset
    If IsNull(Me.cbo_Employee) Or Me.cbo_Employee = "" Then
        MsgBox "You Must enter a Username.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.cbo_Employee.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    strMyUsername = Me.cbo_Employee.Value

    'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

If IsNull(Me.txt_Password) Or Me.txt_Password = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
    Me.txt_Password.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Employees Table] WHERE [Username] = '" & strMyUsername & "'", dbOpenSnapshot)

'Check value of password in Employees Table to see if this matches value chosen in combo box
If Me.txt_Password.Value <> Nz(RS!Password) Then
    MsgBox "Password Invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
    Me.txt_Password.SetFocus
    Me.txt_Password = Null
    intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
    'If user enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown
    If intLogonAttempts >= 3 Then
        MsgBox "You do not  have access to this database. Please contact your system administrator.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If

Else
    Me.txt_Password = Null
    'Open correct form
    Dim strAccessLevel As String

    strAccessLevel = RS!Admins

    If strAccessLevel = "Admin" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & RS!EmployeeName
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "A"
    ElseIf strAccessLevel = "Manager" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & RS!EmployeeName
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "B"
    ElseIf strAccessLevel = "User" Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & RS!EmployeeName
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "C"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: change the datatype from `long` to `String` the datatype `Variant` would be possible too, but regarding performance and readability of your code avoid it

Comment: I changed the datatype from `long` to `string` however now because of this I'm getting a datatype mismatch error on the line `If Me.txt_Password.Value <> DLookup("Password", "Employees Table", "[Username]=" & lngMyUsername) Then`

Comment: i guess `username` is an ID? in this case replace `username` with column name which contains the same values as your combobox

Comment: Username is not an ID and the combo box is already linked to the username column. However the code that I'm using was designed to work with the username as an ID and this is what i'm trying to change.

Comment: what is the datatype of the field `username` in the DB. maybe you can provide a screenshot of your table (of course anonymised)

Comment: Thank you for this, I have attached the relevant pictures in the question. The datatype is short text.

Comment: Oh, wow. Luckily I wrote "most certainly" and not "definitely". :) --- Can you post a screenshot of the property sheet of `cbo_Employee`, with the tab **Data** selected? Or rather its `Row source` and `Bound column` properties?

Comment: @Andre451 Picture of the properties is attached to the question. It seems the `Row Source` is `Table/Query` and the `Bound Column` is `1`

Comment: Thanks. I just read your edit to the question, that made things clearer. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
So you changed the code already, to use Username instead of UserID. That clears things up.

In this case, use a string variable `strMyUsername`, and for the password check you need to enclose the parameter with `'...'`:

```
' Just to be safe: unmasked ' would break the query
strMyUsername = Replace(strMyUsername, "'", "''")

If Me.txt_Password.Value <> DLookup("Password", "Employees Table", _
    "[Username] = '" & strMyUsername & "'") Then
        ' wrong password...
```

**Edit 2**

This line should work

```
strAccessLevel = DLookup("Admins", "Employees Table", "[Username] = '" & strMyUsername & "'")
```

but of course this won't yet:

```
MsgBox "Welcome " & DLookup("EmployeeName", "Employees Table", "Username=" & strMyUsername)
```

But since you are reading multiple fields from "Employees Table", I suggest a different approach: read all fields at once into a recordset.
Then you can replace all `DLookup` calls by `RS!Field`

`OpenRecordset` belongs after checking that username and password are set.

```
Dim RS As Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Employees Table] WHERE [Username] = '" & strMyUsername & "'", dbOpenSnapshot)

If Me.txt_Password.Value <> Nz(RS!Password) Then
' ...
strAccessLevel = RS!Admins
' ...
MsgBox "Welcome " & RS!EmployeeName
```

**Edit 3**

See [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Set a breakpoint at the `Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` line.
Hover over `strMyUsername` - does it contain the value you expect?
Execute the line.
In the **Immediate window** (Ctrl+G): `? RS.EOF` If EOF is true, there are no records.

`? RS.Name` gives you the SQL. Copy this, create a new query from it, and run it. This will help to figure out why it doesn't get a record.

Comment: Thank you so much, getting somewhere now! After changing over all the variable names from `lngMyUsername` to `strMyUsername` and adding in/replacing the code with yours I now seem to be getting `Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'Username='` on the line `strAccessLevel = DLookup("Admins", "Employees Table", "Username=" & lngMyUsername)`.

Comment: @Giles: You need the same technique as in the password lookup: `"[Username] = '" & strMyUsername & "'"` --- BTW, you can move the `MsgBox "Welcome "...` outside the `If strAccessLevel`, so you don't have this code 3 times.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that first but i'm getting back `Invalid use of Null` on the same line. Cheers for the message box tip!

Comment: I suggest you post the complete revised code in your question, that makes it easier to find the problem.

Comment: Not a problem, all added to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Giles: I don't see anything wrong with your `strAccessLevel = DLookup` line. But see Edit 2.

Comment: I have added your second edit (using `OpenRecordse`t) to my code and have attached that at the bottom of my question. When run the code i'm now getting a `Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)': No current record.` I can confirm that all field and table names used in the code are correct.

Comment: @Giles: Debugging to the rescue! see Edit 3.

Comment: I've done all of edit three apart from running a new query as i'm unsure how to do this however the value in `strMyUsername` is `2` however the username i'm selecting from the combo box is `User` not sure if that's normal. `? RS.EOF` is true, so there are no records. And `? RS.Name` spits back `SELECT * FROM [Employees Table] WHERE [Username] = '2'`

Comment: That's the problem - `Me.cbo_Employee.Value` gives '2' instead of 'User'. Check its properties, the combobox probably still has two columns, with the bound column being the user id. Change the properties under Format and Data to **one** column (username). @Giles

Comment: It works!! Thank's for taking the time to talk me through diagnose my own problem, awesome work.